# Binding multiple CheckBoxes to single property in ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I would like to bind multiple CheckBox items (IsChecked property) to a single property in my ViewModel.

[image: Weekdays]

The ViewModel property is called SelectedWeekdays (int) and is the sum of all the selected weekdays. The idea being that every possible combination of weekday values will always result in a unique sum. The weekdays are defined in an enum as such:

```
public enum Weekdays
{
    Monday = 1
    Tuesday = 2
    Wednesday = 4
    Thursday = 8
    Friday = 16
    Saturday = 32
    Sunday = 64
}
```

So for example if Tuesday and Thursday are selected on the View, this should result in a ViewModel property value of 10.

Likewise, if the ViewModel property changes, say to 3, the CheckBoxes for Monday and Tuesday should be checked.

I've looked at MultiBindings but it seems I could only use that to bind a single CheckBox to multiple values. Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: You might be able to use a [converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.converter(v=vs.110).aspx) but it's been a while since I have worked with WPF.

Comment: Did you think about using a single onClick or valueChanged event linked to all of the checkboxes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this work for you? I didn't implement `ConvertBack`. It should be easy.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;

        SelectedWeekday = Weekdays.Tuesday;
    }

    private Weekdays _selectedWeekday;
    public Weekdays SelectedWeekday
    {
        get { return _selectedWeekday; }
        set
        {
            _selectedWeekday = value;
            if(PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SelectedWeekday"));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}

[Flags]
public enum Weekdays
{
    Monday = 1,
    Tuesday = 2,
    Wednesday = 4,
    Thursday = 8,
    Friday = 16,
    Saturday = 32,
    Sunday = 64
}

public class WeekdayConverter : IValueConverter, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var day = (Weekdays)value;
        if ((day & Weekday) != 0)
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        //Implement convertback
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private Weekdays _weekday;
    public Weekdays Weekday
    {
        get { return _weekday; }
        set
        {
            _weekday = value;
            if(PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Weekday"));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:view="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <view:WeekdayConverter x:Key="MondayConverter" Weekday="Monday"></view:WeekdayConverter>
        <view:WeekdayConverter x:Key="TuesdayConverter" Weekday="Tuesday"></view:WeekdayConverter>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <CheckBox Content="Monday" IsChecked="{Binding SelectedWeekday, Converter={StaticResource MondayConverter}}" />
        <CheckBox Content="Tuesday" IsChecked="{Binding SelectedWeekday, Converter={StaticResource TuesdayConverter}}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: Can you please also add convert back? I want to be able to select multiple checkboxes not just one.